# What does "i7 or equivalent" mean? (Zoom 49 videos feature)

Tags: cpu, zoom-meeting

I see that Zoom supports 49 video thumbnails on a screen at the same time if you have an "i7 or equivalent", however, that doesn't make much sense. I know i7 CPUs that are slower than i3 CPUs. And an i7 is not an i9, but I have to imagine that an i9 could do 49 videos.

From Geekbench (single core / multi core):

- i3: [329 / 747](https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/890)
- i7: [329 / 699](https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/415)

So what does this really mean from a practical standpoint? Is it an instruction that matters, a frequency, a core count?

Comment: Could it mean something like an AMD Ryzen?

Comment: Probably, but I'm wondering how I could know that for sure before buying a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an exact answer you'd need to ask the Zoom team - if they could even answer. Here are some considerations:

**"or equivalent"**:
i7 as you know are Intel processors. AMD has followed Intels denomination scheme, creating Ryzen 3 for i3, Ryzen 5 for i5, Ryzen 7 for i7. And latest: Ryzen 9 for i9. 
So, usually "i7 or equivalent" on the web is intended as: Intel i7 or Ryzen 7.

**specifying**:
To display 49 video feeds needs a combination of multithreading capability for parallel processing, together with 'solid' graphics performance. So, "i7 or equivalent" is just a simplification of a question which doesn't have a simple answer.  You are right in saying that a desktop i3 can have better performance than a notebook i7.

But consider that OEM's will put i7 (or equivalent Ryzen) only into systems which have an overall better performance: graphics, ram, disk speed..., otherwise the premium you pay for an i7 won't pay out.
i7 moreover in (almost) all cases are a guarantee of enabled multithreading and of best integrated graphics, the two things which matter most in this case.
Probably these are some "reasons" for the simplification.

**Practical Side**, since you are considering a new system:
I manage to run Zoom with 49 video thumbs on a 5 years old laptop with a i7-5500U CPU: that's 2 cores, 4 threads @ 2.4GHz. BUT if I have too many other applications running, Zoom will revert to 25 thumbs. Example: if I run the open broadcaster OBS besides Zoom, I have to make sure it's running on my dedicated GPU, otherwise I won't get 49 thumbs. 
Zoom does not need dedicated graphics, it will run on the integrated graphics.

So, considered this example: you can be quite sure that any system with an i7, or i9, (or equivalent Ryzen) you buy NEW* today can handle Zooms 49 thumbs. If you go with an i3 or i5, you could be lucky too, especially if its a desktop, but it depends if the zoom app actually 'checks' the processor (I doubt it does, that would be really silly).

- With NEW I mean: 8th generation Intel or later, or equivalent Ryzen. I would not buy something older unless you know exactly what you're looking for, and why: windows 10 has officially stopped supporting hardware older than 4th generation Intel, and that process won't be stopping.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was that Zoom was specifically limiting CPUs. They've recently updated their client and now support a set of processors that makes a lot more sense (though still appears to be hand-picked):

Supported processors for single monitor

- Intel i5 - 4 cores or higher, gen 4 or higher
- Intel i7, i9, Xeon - 2 cores or higher
- Intel Atom - 6 cores or higher
- Other Intel processors - 6 cores or higher, 3.0GHz frequency or higher
  AMD Ryzen 5 series

Supported processors for dual monitors

- Intel i5 - 4 cores or higher, gen 6 or higher, and 2.0GHz frequency or higher
- Intel i7, i9, Xeon - 4 cores or higher
- Intel Atom - 6 cores or higher and 1.6GHz frequency of higher; or 8 cores or higher
- Other Intel processors - 8 cores or higher, 3.0GHz frequency or higher; or 12 cores or higher
  AMD Ryzen 7/9 series

This requires their 5.2.0 client.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362323-Changing-the-video-layout-Active-Speaker-View-and-Gallery-View-